# Any way to save checkbox state in URL as an end user of a site?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cgi

I shop at Giant grocery stores here on the east coast of the USA, and their web site allows you to view available coupons.  They often show coupons for items in which I typically have no interest (bathroom and laundry stuff).  Usually I'm just interested in the coupons for food, so to have to wade through the other stuff is a hassle.  They have a "Filter" that allows me to check the boxes for the things I want to see, and anything not checked will not be displayed, but I have to re-do the checking every time I go to the page.  And with each checking of a box, it has to "think" for a minute, before I can check another checkbox.

Is there some way to save the "checked" status of certain checkboxes (perhaps in the URL), so that I don't have to re-apply the filter each time I visit the page?

Here's the page in question:

https://giantfoodstores.com/coupons-weekly-circular/digital-coupons/#/available

Thanks!

```
  Doug
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to save the checkboxes if the page isn't offering a checkbox "save service" with local storage or something similar.